# Объясните смысл выражения

Tags: java

Что на картинке значит подчёркнутое жирной чертой выражение?
[image]

То есть `Color` у нас класс, но что тогда `Red`?

Comment: Значит Цвет.Красный.

Comment: Псмотрите код, как объявлен этот самый класс Color (и возможно это не класс)

Comment: В том то и дело, что в книге приведён только этот фрагмент

Comment: Приведите код текстом, а не картинкой

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Color.Red` это константа класса `Color`, a может быть и перечислением. Например

```
enum Color {
  Red, Green, Blue
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы, наверное, пропустили пару страниц в учебнике. Red это поле класса. В данном случае используется наверняка стандартный класс [Color](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html).